# Rendering Fetched API data on component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I am trying to render a job card component, I fetched data from an API and I want to display the card on another component. It data shows that it fetched on my console when I check from the job card component, by it does display on the search result component. I checked the length from the search result which is where I want to render the component and it shows 0. I don't know where or what the issue, there no error to see where I can trace it from. The writing the app with vite.

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import JobCard from "./JobCard";

const SearchResults = ({ jobResults }) => {
  console.log("Job Results Length:", jobResults.length);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-light">Search Results</h2>
      {jobResults.length > 0 &&
        jobResults.map((job, index) => <JobCard key={index} job={job} />)}
    </div>
  );
};

SearchResults.propTypes = {
  jobResults: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      job_id: PropTypes.string,
      job_title: PropTypes.string,
      job_description: PropTypes.string,
      employer_name: PropTypes.string,
      job_employment_type: PropTypes.string,
      job_apply_link: PropTypes.string,
      job_city: PropTypes.string,
      job_state: PropTypes.string,
      job_country: PropTypes.string,
      job_is_remote: PropTypes.bool,
      job_posted_at_datetime_utc: PropTypes.string,
      job_required_experience: PropTypes.string,
    })
  ),
};

export default SearchResults;
```

the Search Bar component

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { fetchJobs } from "../services/jobService";

const Searchbar = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    try {
      const jobResults = await fetchJobs(query);

      if (jobResults.status === "OK") {
        const relevantJobs = jobResults.data || [];
        console.log("Relevant Jobs:", relevantJobs);

        
      } else {
        console.error("Error response from server:", jobResults.status);
        
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error in handleSearch:", error);
      
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative flex lg:flex-row flex-col flex-1 lg:bottom-20 lg:w-[70%] bg-white p-5  shadow-xl rounded-md ">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search a Job Ex: Python developer in Texas, USA"
        onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        className="border p-2 lg:w-[80%] pl-4 outline-none text-secondary lg:text-sm lg:rounded-l-lg "
      />

      <button
        onClick={() => handleSearch(query)}
        className="bg-primary hover:opacity-90 lg:mt-0 mt-5 text-white lg:text-[15px] lg:rounded-r-lg  lg:p-2 p-4 font-bold lg:ml-10 lg:px-10"
      >
        Search
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Searchbar;
```

The Fetch API component

```
const API_URL = "https://jsearch.p.rapidapi.com/search";

const fetchJobs = async (query) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    query: query,
    page: "1",
    num_pages: "1",
  });

  const headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_API_SECRET_KEY,
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "jsearch.p.rapidapi.com",
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}?${params}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: headers,
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
      return data;
    } else {
      console.error("Error response from server:", response.status, data);
      throw new Error(`Server error: ${response.status}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching jobs:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export { fetchJobs };
```

Comment: please also provide where you actually perform the call to your API

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is how you are storing the jobs. You need to store the fetched jobs in a state. Pass this state to the `SearchResults` component as prop.

Here are the changes that you need to do in the `SearchBar` component:

```
// Previous code
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]); // add a state to store the search results

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    try {
      const jobResults = await fetchJobs(query);

      if (jobResults.status === "OK") {
        const relevantJobs = jobResults.data || [];
        setJobs(relevantJobs); // Store the filtered results in the state
        console.log("Relevant Jobs:", relevantJobs);

        
      } else {
        console.error("Error response from server:", jobResults.status);
        
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error in handleSearch:", error);
      
    }
  };
```

Now call the `SearchResults` component by passing this state as prop:

```
<SearchResults jobResults={jobs} />
```

Comment: I made a mistake i was supposed to add the fetch api component not the searchbar, my components are rendered in App.jsx, i pass in <SearchResults jobResults={jobResults} /> in my App